# problema con array java

Tags: java, array, string

Estoy haciendo el juego del *tres en raya*, pero a la hora de comprobar si una casilla del array esta tachada no me lo hace.

**Código:**

Jugador es una clase, y lista_jugadores en un arraylist, lo que hago es ver si un jugador esta intentando tachar una casilla que ya tiene el símbolo de otro jugador, pero no entra a ese if no se por que, tengo el mismo problema en otra parte del código, debe de ser el mismo problema, por eso he puesto este que es el mas corto

```
    if(tablero[x][y].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(0).getSimbolo_jugador())) {
        System.out.println("ya esta tachada");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor comparte mas código, donde estas cargando el array de lista_jugadores?

Comment: Que tipo de dato retorna `getSimbolo_jugador()`? String?

Comment: El metodo getSimbolo_jugador retorna un string, mediante un metodo que doy de alta jugadores, añado en esa lista loa jugadores, si utilizo el equals para identificar si el segundo jugador es la maquina me lo compara, pero en esa sentencia exactamente no..

Comment: Parece que es por que tu string no es igual... y tiene sentido si el simbolo del jugador es X en vez de O nunca entrará cambia ese equals por un matches("O|X")